# Formatting email items in VBA

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I'm working on VBA to format an email that will have different text based on the values in the CheckReturnReason column in t1stNoticeEmails table.

I'm trying to format it so that if the specific reason is only listed once in the table, the email is formatted a specific way with a table displayed inside of it, and if a reason is listed more than once, a spreadsheet is attached with the information.  This is how the code currently looks, which does not include anything addressing the Excel attachment for multiple entries.

How would I include different formatting if rst2.RecordCount > 1?

```
Sub FirstEmail_DuplicatePayment_ReviewVBA()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim strTableBeg As String
Dim strTableBody As String
Dim strTableEnd As String
Dim strFntNormal As String
Dim strTableHeader As String
Dim strFntEnd As String
Dim CheckNum As String
Dim NameOfRecipient As String
Dim StrSQL1 As String
Dim NameSpaceOutlook As Outlook.Namespace
Dim sAddressText As String
Dim sAddress1 As Variant
Dim sAddress2 As Variant
Dim sAddressCity As Variant
Dim sAddressState As Variant
Dim sAddressZip As Variant

gPARAttachment = "S:\UPAY\Z_NewStructure\..."

'SEND FIRST NOTICE EMAILS'
'------------------'

Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select distinct ContactEmails from t1stNoticeEmails WHERE CheckReturnReason = 'DuplicatePayment'")


If rst2.RecordCount = 0 Then 'checks if recordset returns any records and continues if records found and exits if no records found
    Exit Sub
End If

rst2.MoveFirst

'Create e-mail item
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Do Until rst2.EOF

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Define format for output
strTableBeg = "<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0>"
strTableEnd = "</table>"
strTableHeader = "<font size=3 face='Calibri'><b>" & _
                    "<tr bgcolor=#4DB84D>" & _
                        td("CheckNumber") & _
                        td("PayeeName") & _
                        td("VendorID") & _
                        td("DocNo / ERNo / PONo") & _
                        td("Amount") & _
                        td("CheckDate") & _
                        "</tr></b></font>"
strFntNormal = "<font color=black face='Calibri' size=3>"
strFntEnd = "</font>"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM t1stNoticeEmails where ContactEmails='" & rst2!ContactEmails & "' AND CheckReturnReason = 'DuplicatePayment' " _
& "Order by FullName asc")

If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
    rst2.Close
    Set rst2 = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

sAddress1 = rst!OriginalCheckAddress1
sAddress2 = rst!OriginalCheckAddress2
sAddressCity = rst!OriginalCheckCity
sAddressState = rst!OriginalCheckState
sAddressZip = rst!OriginalCheckZip
sAddressText = "<Font face='Calibri'>" _
& "The following check(s) sent to " _
& sAddress1 & " " & sAddress2 & " " & sAddressCity & " " & sAddressState & " " & sAddressZip _
& " have been returned to the University by the payee. <br><br>"

rst.MoveFirst

NameOfRecipient = rst!FullName
CheckNum = rst!CheckNumber

'Build HTML Output for the DataSet
strTableBody = strTableBeg & strFntNormal & strTableHeader

Do Until rst.EOF
    strTableBody = _
    strTableBody & _
    "<tr>" & _
    "<TD nowrap>" & rst!CheckNumber & "</TD>" & _
    "<TD nowrap>" & rst!FullName & "</TD>" & _
    "<TD nowrap>" & rst![VendorID/UIN] & "</TD>" & _
    "<TD nowrap>" & rst![DocNo / ERNo / PONo] & "</TD>" & _
    "<TD align='right' nowrap>" & Format(rst!AmountDue, "currency") & "</TD>" & _
    "<TD nowrap>" & rst!OriginalCheckDate & "</TD>" & _
    "</tr>"
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
'rst.MoveFirst

strTableBody = strTableBody & strFntEnd & strTableEnd

'rst.Close

'Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select distinct ch_email from t_TCard_CH_Email")
'rst2.MoveFirst



Call CaptureDPBodyText

With objMail
    'Set body format to HTML
    .To = rst2!ContactEmails
    .BCC = gDPEmailBCC
    .Subject = gDPEmailSubject & " - Check# " & CheckNum & " - " & NameOfRecipient
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody

    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<HTML><BODY>" & strFntNormal & sAddressText & strTableBody & " </BODY></HTML>"

    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & gDPBodySig

    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "..."
    .Attachments.Add gPARAttachment
    .Display
    '.Send
End With

rst2.MoveNext

'Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
rst2.Close
Set rst2 = Nothing

End Sub`
```

Comment: FYI variables `StrSQL1` and `NameSpaceOutlook` are neither assigned nor used. Protip: avoid such wall-of-declarations-at-the-top, and declare variables immediately before you assign them. You'll reduce the constant back-and-forth scrolling up and down while debugging/maintaining the code, you'll easily avoid declaring variables you're not using, and you'll remove the "need" to have that [useless Systems Hungarian](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) prefix on everything, thereby doubly enhancing readability.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `RecordCount` is not reliable with Access. I use something like `rst.BOF=true AND rst.EOF=true` to check for no returned records.

To see if more than one record was returned use

```
rst.MoveNext    
if rst.EOF=false then <more than one record>
```

right after

```
rst.MoveFirst
```

essentially checking if reading after the first record got you to the end of the data.

Comment: I made that change and it didn't work.  Now it returns that 'If' condition in all cases--so even if there is only one record or multiple records in the recordset.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you also need `rst.MoveNext` right after `rst.MoveFirst` for the cursor to actually hit the end of the recordset. I edited my answer.